# how to use nb-select & nb-option

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

'nb-option' is not a known element:
1. If 'nb-option' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'nb-option' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

**component.html**

```
<nb-card-body>
  <nb-select placeholder="10" [(ngModel)]="defaultRowPerPage">
    <nb-option (click)="setPager()" value="10">10</nb-option>
    <nb-option (click)="setPager()" value="20">20</nb-option>
    <nb-option (click)="setPager()" value="50">50</nb-option>
    <nb-option (click)="setPager()" value="100">100</nb-option>
  </nb-select>
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="source" >
</ng2-smart-table>
</nb-card-body>
```

**module.ts**

```
const NB_MODULES = [
  NbCardModule,
  NbLayoutModule,
  NbTabsetModule,
  NbRouteTabsetModule,
  NbMenuModule,
  NbUserModule,
  NbActionsModule,
  NbSearchModule,
  NbSidebarModule,
  NbCheckboxModule,
  NbPopoverModule,
  NbContextMenuModule,
  NgbModule,
  NbSecurityModule,
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss NbSelectModule in the imports